# snmpd.conf clientaddr not working for sending trap /inform with given IP source address

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, rhel7, snmp-trap, snmpd

Given the following sample/simple snmpd.conf (Net-SNMP 5.7.2 on RHEL 7.4)

> rwcommunity private 192.168.56.101
>
> trapsess -Ci **--clientaddr=192.168.56.128** -v 2c -c private 192.168.56.101:162

when starting a SNMP Daemon

> snmpd -f -Lo **-D** -C -c data/snmpd_test.conf udp:192.168.56.128:161

We obtain *''Start Up''* InformRequest with IP source ***192.56.168.1*** instead of **...128** (WireShark snapshot below)

[image: InformRequest with source 1 instead of 128]

It is not surprising as the **-D** option allows us to output the debug information saying that

> trace: netsnmp_config_process_memory_list(): read_config.c, 696:
>   read_config:mem: processing memory: clientaddr 192.168.56.128
>   trace: run_config_handler(): read_config.c, 562:
>   9:read_config:parser: **clientaddr handler not registered for this time**

Web sources however say:

[snmp.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/snmp.conf)

*...This value is also used by snmpd when generating notifications.*

[snmpd.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/snmpd.conf)

*trapsess [SNMPCMD_ARGS] HOST*
*provides a more generic mechanism for defining notification destinations.*
*SNMPCMD_ARGS* *should be the command-line options required for an equivalent*
*snmptrap (or snmpinform) command to send the desired notification*

I read also some old threads like [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/12944573/)

- However this option is working well with snmptrap

  > snmptrap -D -Lo -Ci --clientaddr=192.168.56.128 -M+path_to_my_mibs  -v 2c -c private 192.168.56.101:162 "" .1.3.6.1.4.1.a.b.c.d.e.f.0 i 0

[image: correct snmpinform with ip source 128]

- This option is also working when placed in snmp.conf ( mind there is no 'd' here ) and then it applies to snmpset and snmpget (and maybe other)

So my question is: Is it a documentation error, a bug, a misuse of the Net-SNMP stack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle I may have an answer and I write a short note as I just found a trick

> It seems that **clientaddr** is not parsed correctly **wherever** in the **snmpd.conf**

(I tried not also inside the *trapsess* line)

> But it seems to be a valid option **in the command line** of **snmpd**

like it was a valid option in the *snmptrap* command line. So I assumed it could be the same parsing mechanism for both.

> a condition also is that the IP addres must be valid one

which means that

> snmpd -f -Lo -D -C -c data/snmpd_test.conf **--clientaddr=192.168.56.128** udp:192.168.56.128:161

seems to fully solve my problem.

I will perform more tests and if accurate format this answer a little bit better but it seems a good hint.